# AWS redrive to source queue from dql queue., using an API in code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

So in december 2021, AWS launched "DLQ redrive to source queues allows SQS to manage the lifecycle of unconsumed messages stored in DLQs."

Can this be done through code? Can i, say, call this from java and hit an api with say source queue arn and dlq arn as arguments and it takes care of redriving?

I have already done this using pull message off dlq queue, and then push it onto source queue using java. that was before this feature was available.

Comment: I think the UI does **exactly** what you you did previously. I do not see an API for that.

Answer (score 2):

DLQ redrive SDK/CLI support has been launched!! https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/a-new-set-of-apis-for-amazon-sqs-dead-letter-queue-redrive/

Answer (score 0):

DLQ Redrive is not available to do programmatically right now, for now, the only way to Redrive is going to *SQS console* -> *Go to your DLQ* -> *Select "DLQ Redrive"*

More information can be found here: [Introducing Amazon Simple Queue Service dead-letter queue redrive to source queues](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-simple-queue-service-dead-letter-queue-redrive-to-source-queues/#:%7E:text=DLQ%20redrive%20to%20source%20queues%20enables%20SQS%20to%20manage%20the,back%20to%20the%20source%20queue.)